# How to create Hub Proxy using AspNetCore SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Anyone know the AspNetCore SignalR equivalent of this code from AspNet SignalR?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    ////  var clients = Hub.Clients<RealTimeNotificationHub>();
    var connection = new HubConnectionContext("https://demohouse.go.ro:96/");
    var notificationmessag = new AlertMessage();
    notificationmessag.Content = "New message from " + device.Name + " <b>" +
                                 text + " </b>";
    notificationmessag.Title = alertType.Name;
    var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("realTimeNotificationHub");
    connection.Start().Wait();
    object[] myData = { notificationmessag.Title, notificationmessag.Content };
    myHub.Invoke("sendMessage", myData).Wait();
    connection.Stop();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add Nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client and try the below code. I took the liberty to use your data on your post and translate it to the .Net Core version.

```
//I'm not really sure how your HUB route is configured, but this is the usual approach.

var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("https://demohouse.go.ro:96/realTimeNotificationHub") //Make sure that the route is the same with your configured route for your HUB
                .Build();

var notificationmessag = new AlertMessage();
notificationmessag.Content = "New message from " + device.Name + " <b>" +
                                         text + " </b>";
notificationmessag.Title = alertType.Name;

connection.StartAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        //Do something if the connection failed
    }
    else
    {
        //if connection is successfull, do something
        connection.InvokeAsync("sendMessage", myData);

    }).Wait();
```

You can use a different approach on executing async tasks.

Note: Your Hub should be also using the .Net Core package for SignalR (Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR) in order for this to work (based on my experience).

Comment: I've changed the URL the one I configured in my Startup.cs file. It looks like this now: withUrl("localhost:64017/scan"). But nothing happens when I invoke the method. Shouldn't it call the method from my hub? or from the javascript file?

Comment: Never mind. Something else was the issue why it wasn't calling the Hub method. Your answer works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: @LukeVillanueva, will it send messages to all clients? I've tried in the same way to have shown here, I can find connection id and state connected. However, js code doesn't received it at all. Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59840085/4753489

Answer (score 0):

```
private HubConnection connection;
  
string url = "http://Server:port/Hub_Name";
        
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(url)
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
             .Build();
       
 connection.StartAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
  if (task.IsFaulted)
     {
         //Do something if the connection failed
    }
     else
    {
        //if connection is successfull, do something
        connection.InvokeAsync("sendMessage", myData);

    }).Wait();
 }
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. Not sure where it is getting failed. Is there any alternate to create the hub proxy. Please provide your inputs @LukeVillanueva

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).