# SignalR .NET Core 3.x replacement for IHubProxy

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to convert a .NET Framework project to a .NET Core 3.0 project that has a bunch of SignalR. For the most part I seem to have been able to find the upgrade path, with one exception; IHubProxy.

Is there some documentation somewhere that I can look at that explains the replacement for IHubProxy?

Below is some sample code that represents what I am trying to replace.

```cs
private static async Task<IHubProxy> getHubProxy(string name)
{
    var hubConnection = new HubConnection(BaseUrl);
    var proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(name);

    try
    {
        await hubConnection.Start();

        Logger.Info("Proxy started....");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error($"Couldn't start the proxy: {name}", ex);
        proxy = null;
    }
    return proxy;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Hub Proxy using AspNetCore SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550773/how-to-create-hub-proxy-using-aspnetcore-signalr)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: [How to create Hub Proxy using AspNetCore SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550773/how-to-create-hub-proxy-using-aspnetcore-signalr)

I'll close this as a duplicate as soon as it allows, or if someone runs across this and can mark as duplicate, please do.